# Is it a highly trained mouse?

Tags: film-techniques, mousehunt

The mouse used in [Mousehunt](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119715/), the mouse is shown extra ordinarily clever. Was that a real mouse used in that movie or another computer created bug? Whatever it is, it seemed very real!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [**Cinema Review**](http://www.cinemareview.com/production.asp?prodid=9):

> It is actually an ensemble performance delivered by **a combination of real mice, an animatronic mouse and a computer-generated (CGI) mouse.**

Animal trainer [Boone Narr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boone_Narr) trained ...

> ... **60 mice to perform the complex stunts and tricks** they would have to perform in the film.
>
> Grouped in teams of four or five, the mice had to be taught to do basic running and climbing stunts, as well as more intricate actions, including climbing into a sardine can bed beneath a tissue paper comforter.
>
> The mice became so beloved that many of the "Mouse Hunt" cast and crew adopted them after shooting was completed.

The visual effects company [**Rhythm & Hues**](http://www.rhythm.com/features/credits/mouse-hunt/) was responsible for the *computer generated mouse*.

> According to Rhythm & Hues' visual effects supervisor *Charles Gibson*:
>
> - *"The goal with 'Mouse Hunt's' visual effects was to make people believe we had the world's most amazing trained mouse, and never a CGI creation."*

The *animatronic mouse* came from [**Stan Winston Studios**](http://www.ew.com/ew/gallery/0,,20207033_20439407,00.html).

[**VFX HQ**](http://www.vfxhq.com/1997/mousehunt.html) has an article about the *CG mouse*.

Comment: I must say they were successful in showing it was a real mouse indeed!

Answer (score 3):

From what I recall, I think it's a mix of real life and cgi, depending on the scene you're watching.  In a good portion of the movie I believe they used a train mouse, and for the more complex scenes (liek when the mouse was knocked out if I remember correctly) they used cgi.

This is all based on my memory though so I have to references for you.